# Does HERE Maps 4.x support Objective-C projects for migrate?

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

Good day HERE Maps Team!
We have a project on Objective-C for iOS.
We can't figure out if the new version 4.x supports migration for Obj-C?
Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no Obj-C support in HERE SDK 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Currently we are supporting Swift 5.3.2 - or higher in SDK 4.x.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-explore/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/about.html#minimum-requirements